# Adding in-it parameters to servlet filter while spring injection

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to add spring injection to servlet. In web.xml of my project

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>Helloworld</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>Helloworld</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/hello/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

In Spring.xml

```
<bean id="Helloworld" class="com.abc.Helloworld">       
</bean>
```

There is one in-it parameter for my filter. I am confused whether I can add this parameter as property to bean or in  element of web.xml.

Which would be best or correct

**1. In spring.xml under bean Helloworld**

```
<property name="greet">
      <value>Hello</value>
   </property>
```

**2. In web.xml under filter Helloworld as**

```
<init-param>
         <param-name>greet</param-name>
         <param-value>Hello</param-value>    
</init-param>
```

Please suggest whether to follow approach 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would almost certainly put it in Spring, where the rest of your application configuration is.

Why would you even need to use `DelegatingFilterProxy` if you were thinking of configuring this `Filter` in the deployment descriptor?